# What could Entity Framework have to do with Interop.SHDocVw?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, edmx

I have a project that we've recently modified. The project is written in .NET, and compiled for x64 machines. I have a DataEntities model that we've built to interact with our database. However, when we try to connect to the entity framework model, we get an error.

The entity framework edmx file is called DataCentral.edmx. Using this file, the code we are trying to run to connect to our instance is blindingly simple.

```
        string cs = CSManager.GetConnectionString();
        DataCentralEntities ctx = new DataCentralEntities(cs);
```

When we run these two lines, it crashes at the second line with an inner-inner exception of:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.SHDocVw, Version=1.1.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. 
An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

When we run it as x86 (which isn't possible in the long-term for other reasons) it runs just fine. I did check the connection string and it is formatted correctly.

Here's my question: I don't use ShDocVw in any of my new changes. In fact, I had never even heard of it until I ran into this error. What the heck could cause this to puke here? What's going on that I'm missing?

**UPDATE**

We found a form that was built probably right around the time of .NET 2.0. (Maybe even earlier.) It created a reference to a web browser control (not the official WebBrowser control) through the ShDocVw library. Apparently, this was a fairly common way of embedding a web browser into your app before the official control came along.

We upgraded this form to use the official WebBrowser control, and removed all references in our project to ShDocVw.dll, and everything is now working as-expected, even in x64.

What I still don't understand is why Entity Framework crashes on that line when a reference to ShDocVw.dll is in your project. That part makes no sense to me. However, we are back on our feet now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some cases EntityFramework is trying to load assemblies referenced by your main assembly (most notably it happens when EF is looking for precompiled views). In your case this causes an exception this will cause loading 32-bit assembly into 64-bit process. Note that the same would have happend if anything else tried loading this assembly. You need to either use 64-bit assembly or built your project as 32-bit. Another option is to use Corflags to set your starting assembly as 32-bit which will cause creating 32-bit process on a 64-bit machine and therefore you will be able to load the assembly that previously caused the problem.